# Matrix element alignment in Tikz

Tags: tikz-matrix

Im trying to align the elements of the matrix to the left but its not working. Any idea?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}  


\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{xxxxx}
\underline{\textbf{Example}}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\rightarrow$] Let's consider two systems of linear equations that correspond to the same coefficient matrix $\mathbf{A}$
\end{itemize}




\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline]
   \tikzstyle{column 8}=[myblue]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,column/.style={anchor=base west},ampersand replacement=\&](A){ 
    3 x_1  \&+ 5x_2    \& -4x_3   \& = \&7\\
    - 3 x_1 \& -2x_2  \& +4x_3   \& = \&  -1\\
      6  x_1 \& +x_2   \& -8x_3    \& =\&   -4\\
   };
   \end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See if answers on the (similar) question can help you : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563571/columns-are-not-aligned-in-beamer/563580#563580

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 3):

Are you obligated to use `tikz` for writing your system of equations (as matrix)? If not, you can use simple `array`:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{xxxxx}
\underline{\textbf{Example}}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\rightarrow$] Let's consider two systems of linear equations that correspond to the same coefficient matrix $\mathbf{A}$
\end{itemize}

\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rrr >{\color{myblue}}r}
  3 x_1 + & 5x_2 - & 4x_3 = &   7\\
- 3 x_1 - & 2x_2 + & 4x_3 = &  -1\\
  6 x_1 + &  x_2 - & 8x_3 = &  -4\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To left-align matrix elements, you can set the style for each cell by `cells={anchor=west}` or `nodes={anchor=west}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}  


\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{xxxxx}
\underline{\textbf{Example}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\rightarrow$] Let's consider two systems of linear equations that correspond to the same coefficient matrix $\mathbf{A}$
\end{itemize}



\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,baseline]
    \tikzstyle{column 8}=[myblue]
    \matrix [matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,cells={anchor=west}](A){ 
        3 x_1  \&+ 5x_2    \& -4x_3   \& = \&7\\
        - 3 x_1 \& -2x_2  \& +4x_3   \& = \&  -1\\
          6  x_1 \& +x_2   \& -8x_3    \& =\&   -4\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]